# Footer background image css

Tags: css, xhtml, footer

Good Day,
I am having this problem about my footer image not stretching when I resize my browser.
I tried using sticky footer but I don't think it works.

I am using 960 grid for my layout so I had to create a different div to wrap my footer background so it runs across the browser...

For some reason, there is this white space at the bottom of my background image (in the footer section) when I stretch the browser.

My xhtml goes something like this.. Please feel free to preview my site here: http://www.ofsgraphics.com/ofsv3

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="contentMainBackground"></div> <!-- background image for content */
             <div id="contentMain" class="container_12"></div>

    </div><!-- end of container -->         

    <div id="footerMainBackground"></div><!-- background image for footerMainBackground -->
         <div id="footer" class="container_12"></div>


CSS:
    #footerMainBackground {
        background:url("../images/footer_bg.jpg") repeat;
        min-height:150px;
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        overflow:hidden;
        clear:both;
    }
        #footer {
        padding:30px 0 0 0;
        }
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do is to put that background image on your body, and have every other element have their background.

The body should also be width 100% and height 100%.

So now your background will take all the page that is not covered by another div.

Comment: Thank you... something like this would work?
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fixed-footer-backgrounds-with-css/

Comment: Thanks, I think it is working so far... I still have a long way to go (create subpages, IE testing) Greatly appreciated!